# powershell - write errors to .txt file and in one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to log the process in a text file and there are two problems:
1. How to write errors in a text file? Now when the e-mails are not sent, nothing is logged.
2. I need to write time, date and event in a single line

Now I have this in log.txt:

```
17. feb. 2012 10:47:34
Chyba: .gpg neexistuje
17. feb. 2012 10:57:28
Test.gpg existuje.
```

This is my code:

```
function write-log{
param(
[string]$mytext,
[string]$fgc
)
if(!$fgc){$fgc="Black"}
write-host $mytext -foregroundcolor $fgc
$myfile = "c:\gnupg\subor\log.txt"
Get-Date | Out-File $myfile -append
$mytext | Out-File $myfile -append
}

if(test-path "d:\vm\shared pre ws08R2+SQL05\SFRB\*.chk") {
echo "Subor .chk existuje a jeho nazov je " 
get-childitem "d:\vm\shared pre ws08R2+SQL05\SFRB\*.chk" -Name
$a = get-childitem "d:\vm\shared pre ws08R2+SQL05\SFRB\*" -include *.chk -name | Foreach-Object {$a -replace ".chk", ""}

if(test-path d:\vm\"shared pre ws08R2+SQL05"\SFRB\$a.gpg) {
    Write-Log $a".gpg existuje." Green

    Write-Log "Presuvam do banky subor $a.gpg.." Green

    Move-Item "d:\vm\shared pre ws08R2+SQL05\SFRB\$a.gpg" c:\gnupg\subor\$a.gpg
    Write-Log "Presun ukonceny." Green

    Write-Log "Presuvam do banky subor $a.chk.." Green
    Move-Item "d:\vm\shared pre ws08R2+SQL05\SFRB\$a.chk" c:\gnupg\subor\$a.chk
    Write-Log "Presun ukonceny. Subor je pripraveny na spracovanie." Green

    Write-Log "Posielam notifikacne maily.." Green
    $emailFrom = "sfrbControlMsg@primabanka.sk"
    $emailTo = "msic@primabanka.sk"
    $subject = "subject"
    $body = "subor presunuty"
    $smtpServer = "87.244.217.54"
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
    # Write-Log "Maily odoslane." Green

        }
        else {
                Write-Log " Chyba: $a.gpg neexistuje" Magenta
        }
} else {
Write-log "V cielovom adresari neexistuje ziadny subor .chk."
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make use of the inbuilt `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet with parameter `-ErrorAction Stop`.
2. Use a try-catch around this (see *[about_try_catch_finally](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315350.aspx)* to pick up and handle any errors.

   In the `catch` block `$_` will be the error message (as would be shown on the console), and has an `Exception` property which is the (.NET) `Exception` (or subclass) instance (I use `$_.Exception.GetType()` below to specifically report this type as it is an important part of any diagnostics):

Eg. in a script I have:

```
    try {
        $trans = (MakeSummaryMessage) + "`r`n`r`n" + $trans
        Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom `
                        -To $emailTo `
                        -SmtpServer $emailServer `
                        -Subject $subject" `
                        -Body $trans `
                        -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) `
                        -ErrorAction Stop
        $emailSent = $true
    } catch {
        
        Write-EventLog -LogName $eventLog -Source $eventSource -EntryType "Error" `
            -EventId 100 -Message "Failed to send email: $($_.Exception.GetType()): $_"
    }
```